# How does jQuery event namespace works

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events

I would like to understand how jQuery event namespacing works across different browsers.

I don't see anything about this on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event) and I would like to know how to namespace events without using jQuery as well (on older IE as well on modern browsers)

---

#### Update (Oct 1st, 2017):

If anyone is interested, I've answered in another question how to write *minimal* events emitter with **namespaces** in Vanilla JavaScript:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44432013/104380

Comment: jQuery [trigger](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event/trigger.js) source code

Answer (score 3):

jQuery event namespaces are exactly that – **jQuery** event namespaces.

This feature is unique to jQuery; the DOM doesn't have anything like it.

The point of event namespaces is the ability to remove your event handlers by name only; the DOM APIs don't do that at all.

Comment: I know what they are and what they do, i want to know how they work so I could write my own code which does the same, without jQuery (so events won't collide)

Comment: @vsync: Read the jQuery source.  You can maintain an object of event handlers for each namespace and loop over them when raising events.